# view ubuntu one files from another computer

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

I have set up an account and uploaded folders form my main machine. I can view these folders/files from that machine just fine.

From another machine I log onto my Ubuntu one account and cannot see those files. I get a message saying: The remote application did not send a reply.

I don't want these files/folders sync'd I just want access to my files/folders from any machine I am on. As if I am using a friends system I don't want my files/folders sync'd to their machine.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for a quick way to access your files from a friend's system, just browse to http://one.ubuntu.com/, log in, and click the 'Files' tab.

From there, you should be able to browse your synchronised files, and download the ones you want.

Comment: Thanks, that simply what I was looking for and found no simple expiation doing a Google search.

I was also confused when the "services" tab sad to drag and drop any file or folder into the local Ubuntu folder that that would add them to my list. What it did was move the folder to the Ubuntu folder and that was not what I expected. I did not want my desktop or documents folder moved out of my home folder.

Thanks for your help. How do I mark this as solved?

Bob.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. To mark it as solved, there should be a tick button just under the up/down vote buttons. Just click that.